# Show that the time complexity of this double loop is O(n)

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

How would you show that this entire sequence of loops is O(n)? Or is it O(n)? At first glance, just looking at the double loops one might think it's O(n^2) but I don't think it is...

```
int i = 0;
int arr[N];
int idx = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < N/2; j++)
    {
      idx = (i * N/2) + j;
      foo(arr[idx]);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer loop is constant, so the loop is the same as doing:

```
for (j = 0; j < N/2; j++)
{
  idx = (0 * N/2) + j;
  foo(arr[idx]);
  idx = (1 * N/2) + j;
  foo(arr[idx]);
}
```

Which actually makes the intent of the code a lot clearer also, but as you can see, the amount of operations scales linearly with N, so it's O(N) complexity rather than exponential growth. I can't explain it any better as it's 8.30am and I haven't slept, but I imagine you get my gist.